# Mock call to write()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a logger class that needs to write strings to file.  So, I have a method like so:

```
def write_to_file(self, string):
  self.__file_handle.write(string)
```

Note that error handling has been edited out.  Clearly I want to test this without writing to a file.  Thus mocks via [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html).  I have seen [this](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mocking-open) which explains how to mock open but it does not help me here -- I open the file_handle in `__init__`.  Now, I can do that in setUp() but the mock_open seems to go out of scope after setUp and thus is of no use in the test case.

**How would you write a test method to test the write_to_file method using Mock?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reached here from google, only to realize after a while that this has been builtin in mock since 1.0 using [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open)

Answer (score 4):

Simple really...

```
from mock import patch

def setUp(self):
    [...]
    mock_file_handle = Mock()
    with patch('__builtin__.open') as mock_file_handle:
        self.sut = Logger()
    [...]

def test_write(self):
    [...]
    self.sut.write_message_to_file("ook?")
    self.assertTrue(self.sut.file_handle.write.called)
    self.assertTrue(self.sut.file_handle.flush.called)
    [...]
```

If anyone has a better solution, please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the ability to change `__file_handle` in the `__init__`.  As if you replace this with any mock / fake object that has the `.write` signature you can test what is written to it.

Maybe by creating a method that sets up the `__file_handle` and then overwriting the method for this test?

Comment: That is one way.  But it should be possible to mock .write() as well.